# Fine Uploader cannot pass custom paramaters

Tags: php, jquery, fine-uploader

I've been messaging around with this for hours and cannot get it work. 
My implemtation of the fineuploader

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//alert(qq.supportedFeatures.ajaxUploading);
  $('#fine-uploader-house').fineUploader({
  request: {
  endpoint: 'http://ahmdev.localhost/ajax/8pZ1zUUNKSfJftDT8h4zj4N7MpM1xYFcm862v5jfN9I/j3TFxihQ_8PpzIechgJ9_4ktPantebOjOt-pYFBXNtg'
  },
  callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
      this.setParams({'test':'monkey'});
    }
  },
  debug: true,
  multiple: true,
  autoUpload: true,
  validation: {
    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'txt'],
    sizeLimit: 10485760 // 10mb
  },
  retry: {
     enableAuto: true // defaults to false
  },
  text: {
     uploadButton: 'Click or Drop'
  },
  showMessage: function(message) {
  // Using Bootstrap's classes
    $('#restricted-fine-uploader').append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
  },
  deleteFile: {
    enabled: true, // defaults to false
    forceConfirm: true,
    endpoint: '/uploads'
  },
  paramsInBody : true,
  failedUploadTextDisplay: {
    mode: 'custom',
    maxChars: 40,
    responseProperty: 'error',
    enableTooltip: true
  }
});
});
```

I've also tried adding the parameters with the

```
params:{
            fileupload: 'test', 
            fileuploadname: 'monkey'
        }
```

but both have failed to work.

The first thing I output when the endpoint is run is dump the content of $_REQUEST, $_POST and $_GET.
There is nothing in the results.

```
[FineUploader 3.7.0] responseText = <pre>array(2) {
["qquuid"]=>
string(36) "65aacd2f-2b09-4c37-96a1-ac706dba0a79"
["qqtotalfilesize"]=>
string(7) "2912372"
}
</pre><pre>array(2) {
 ["qquuid"]=>
string(36) "65aacd2f-2b09-4c37-96a1-ac706dba0a79"
["qqtotalfilesize"]=>
string(7) "2912372"
}
</pre><pre>array(0) {
}
</pre>
```

Why am I not getting the parameters. I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

print_r($_FILES)

```
Array
(
 [qqfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => IMG_0911.JPG
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php7040.tmp
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 3509155
    )

)
```

Comment: Array
(
    [qqfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => IMG_0911.JPG
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php7040.tmp
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 3509155
        )

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you are not declaring your options correctly. Per the documentation, the params property belongs to the request option.

Correct would be:

```
$('#fine-uploader-house').fineUploader({
  request: {
   endpoint: 'http://ahmdev.localhost/ajax/8pZ1zUUNKSfJftDT8h4zj4N7MpM1xYFcm862v5jfN9I/j3TFxihQ_8PpzIechgJ9_4ktPantebOjOt-pYFBXNtg',
   setParams(Object params, [optional] Integer fileId) // see link below
  },
  callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
    }
  },
```

[Source](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2012/12/09/setparams-is-now-much-more-useful-in-3-1/)

There is also a slightly different method, see http://blog.fineuploader.com/2012/12/05/include-params-in-the-request-body-or-the-query-string/

Comment: This this not correct? callbacks: {
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName) {
      this.setParams({'test':'monkey'});
    }
  },

Comment: Callbacks work a bit differently when using the jQuery plug-in wrapper.  See the [using the jQuery plug-in wrapper](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/integrating/modes/using-jquery-plugin.html) section of the Fine Uploader docs.

Comment: ...or the very top of the [callbacks section of the docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/callbacks.html).